# Force browser to cache some files

Tags: javascript, php, image, caching, dynamic-content

I have a lot of images in a database. The image data is stored in a binary column with an id. I wrote a PHP script that reads this data and outputs the correct Content-type and data.

Whenever I want to display an image on the page, i would put /image.php?id=1 where 1 is the id of the image in the database in the src field of an image tag. This all works well.

Now every time I visit the page again or use javascript to modify the src of some of the images, it seems to load that image again from the server. For example, I have an image: `<img src="/image.php?id=4" />`. When I mouse over this image, i use javascript to dynamically change the src to /image.php?id=5. This causes the image to be loaded again from the server, which takes from 1 to 3 seconds. Preloading this image with a pixel sized image at the start of the document does not work. I am guessing this is because I am actually querying a dynamic PHP script.

Is there any way to made the browser cache the image if they have the same ID? The image ids in my database will rarely change, if ever.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the preloading method must work.

Comment: I don't believe you can cache anything with a "query parameter" in it

Comment: Use a path instead of query parameter (hint: mod_rewrite) and use that as image source.

Comment: You may need to send the appropriate HTTP caching headers to tell the browser how long to cache the images. Though, why are you storing images in a database? That's a bad code smell in my experience.

Comment: @AlexandruG. You should write this as an answer, it works. I never thought of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cached content where the filename only differs by query parameters is not reliable. As example, some proxy servers will treat "style.css?v1" and "style.css?v2" as the same file. This will cause unexpected issues with assets which relies on query parameters as revision numbers.

### Include revision in filename

Each asset that you know it will be changed in the future (*css and js mostly*), will have the revision included in the name or the path:

- `css/style_v1.css` instead of `css/style.css?v1` ( *or* )
- `css/v1/style.css` instead of `css/style.css?v1`

### Filename-based cache busting

This approach will help you if you don't have a build process in place. You will leave the filename with the name untouched (i.e: style.css) and with a bit of help from mod_rewrite you rewrite requests from `/css/style.<revision>.css` to `style.css`.

1. In your HTML:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.432.css">
   ```
2. And from .htaccess you route that request type to `css/style.css`:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svgz?|webp)$ $1.$3 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Next time when you change something in `style.css`, you change from HTML file the revision number of your css file:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.433.css">
   ```

If you are using a VCS, you could even use the current commit as the revision number for your assets, which will help to identify problems in your testing phase, when you often switch between branches to test different aspects of your application.

Read more:

- [Steve Soulders - Revving Filenames: don’t use querystring](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/)
- [Rails Guides: Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)
- [HTML5 Boilerplate - cache busting](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/) - *good and well commented .htaccess example file*

Comment: Good answer. Just a note: your answer seems focused on how not to make the browser use cached version of a file based on a supplied query parameter while I wanted to browser TO use the cached version instead. I used the principles introduced in this answer to make my browser cache the image by rewriting it as a path instead of a query string. Just though I'd mention this in case future users thinks this answer doesn't answer the question.